# Is there any method to compare beans in a list in jsf?

Tags: jsf

I am very new to jsf. i need to compare beans list in jsf. Any way possible?

supposedly the list contains 6 elements. i need to compare
1 and 2, 3 and 4, 5 and 6. any way possible?

his is how i want my expression to be like .......

```
if{#some.path eq "paths installed"} && some.path+1 eq "paths used)} 
then 
{if(#(some.path.substringAfter(':') eq (#(some.path+1.substringAfter(':')
```

... how to give this using jsf?

Comment: Why copy your question and repeat it 6 minutes after you just wrote another one like that? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18524694/how-to-compare-beans-using-rendered-in-jsf

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to do *ALL* your logic using Expression Language. You can just call methods of your JSF managed beans and let standard Java perform this logic.

In your other question you said that you are using `<ui:repeat>`. It has an attribute called `varStatus` which you can use to get the current index of the element of the collection you are iterating over. It may look like this

```
<ui:repeat var="element" value="#{someBean.someCollection}" varStatus="status">
     <!-- Random things you do with #{element} -->
     <!-- To compare two entries you can do this: -->
     <!-- #{someBean.compareElements(someBean.someCollection.get(status.index), someBean.someCollection.get(status.index+1)} -->
     <!-- To avoid IndexOutOfRange use rendered="#{not status.last}" -->
</ui:repeat>
```

Comment: that has almostgot what i want. When i wish to display the list of beans, in this case I have 2 lists, I want the first bean list to be displayed in the left column and next one on the right. The first list contains empty elements too. in those cases the element which has to be displayed in the right column gets displayed in the right.

Comment: #{someBean.compareElements(someBean.someCollection.get(status.index), someBean.someCollection.get(status.index+1)} .. where will i have to put this? and is there any predefined functions for compare

Comment: @Pramoth You put this in your facelets code, obviously. Whereever you need it, or what it should do. EL has some prebuild basic functions for comparison. `eq ` for equality, `ne` for not equal. Also some more arithmetic ones like `le` (less equal) and so forth. For a full list of all operators check the spec: http://www.sws.bfh.ch/~fischli/courses/info/javaee/doc/expression_language-2_2-mrel-spec.pdf